# Why did we keep the tradition of blowing shofar but not silver trumpets?

Tags: halacha, chagim-holidays, shofar, tradition, chatzotzerot-trumpets

The Torah mentions blowing both shofar and hatzotzrot (e.g., http://www.templeinstitute.org/trumpets-gallery.htm) on various occasions during the year, but today we blow only the shofar and only on the yamim noraim.  Why did the tradition keep only the shofar and not the silver trumpet blowing?

Comment: See OC 576 no one knows

Comment: @DoubleAA How appropriate that it’s סימן תקעו

Comment: @DonielF Ok that was funny, literally laughed aloud

Answer (score 7):

In the [Sefer Hachinuch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sefer_ha-Chinuch), *mitzvah* # 484 is blowing the trumpets. As always, the author concludes the discussion by telling us when the *mitzvah* is applicable. In this case he writes that the *mitzvah* of blowing the trumpets is applicable during the times of the Holy Temple:

> ונוהגת מצוה זו בזמן הבית בכהנים שעליהם המצוה לתקוע בחצוצרות

[R. Yom Tov Ashvili](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yom_Tov_Asevilli) writes in his commentary to [Taanit 14a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=10&daf=14&format=pdf) that in France they would never blow on fast days because they didn't have the trumpets:

> ולפי סברא זו נהגו בצרפת שלא לתקוע לעולם בתענית צבור כיון שאין לנו
> חצוצרות

R. Mordechai Spielman sent a question to [R. Moshe Feinstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Feinstein) ([Igrot Moshe O.C. 1:169](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=916&st=&pgnum=291)) asking to explain this comment. Why couldn't we just simply make the trumpets?

> וכי אין אנו יכולים לעשות חצוצרות של כסף

R. Moshe had a lengthy response, the main point of which seems to be that based on Rambam's classification of the different trumpet blowings (Temple-related and non-Temple-related) as only one *mitzvah* it appears that the *mitzvah* of blowing the trumpets in non-Temple-related circumstances is specifically to blow the Temple trumpets. Therefore, as we don't have Temple trumpets, we can't ever blow the trumpets even for the non-Temple-related situations, and it wouldn't help to simply make new trumpets.

> אבל הוא משום **דצריך דוקא חצוצרות שבמקדש** לכן מפרש שהויא המצוה מה לעשות בחצוצרות שציותה תורה לעשות שהוא ממילא מצוה אחת כל מה שתוקעין בהן וזהו אולי כוונת המ"מ בתירוצו **שהמצוה היא אחת כללית לתקוע בחצוצרות במקדש בעת הקרבנות ובעת הצרות** בין במקדש בין בגבולין ואין ראוי למנותן בשתי מצות עיי"ש **ושייך זה רק כשצריך לתקוע באותן החצוצרות דמקדש דוקא** אבל אם היה הדין בכל חצוצרות שאין שייך שתהיה המצוה מה לעשות בחצוצרות אלא שהוא על מעשה התקיעה ודאי הי"ל לחושבם לשתי מצות כמו שחושב תקיעת שופר דר"ה ותקיעת שופר דיוה"כ דיובל בשתי מצות במצוה קל"ז ובמצוה ק"ע וזה סובר הריטב"א אליבא דמנהג צרפת שסברי שהתקיעה בתעניות היא בחצוצרות כדעת הרמב"ם **א"כ הוא דוקא בחצוצרות דמקדש** לכן לא נהגו לתקוע לעולם דהרי אין לנו החצוצרות (my emphasis)

[R. Yosef Shalom Elyashiv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yosef_Shalom_Eliashiv) also has a responsum (Kovetz Teshuvot 2:33) about this question. He cites the Sefer Hachinuch mentioned above that the *mitzvah* is not applicable today, but wonders why this should be the case:

> והנה החינוך מ' שפ"ד כ' מצוה לתקוע בחצוצרות במקדש וכמו"כ בשעת הצרות
> שנא' וכי תבואו מלחמה וכתיב אחריו ג"כ וביום שמחתכם ובמועדיכם ותקעתם כו'
> ונוהגת מצוה זו בזמן הבית בכהנים שעליהם המצוה לתקוע בחצוצרות" ואף זה
> צ"ע למה פקע החיוב לתקוע בעת צרה בזה"ז

He eventually suggests that though the trumpets would not have to have been actually used in the Temple in order to use them for the non-Temple-related circumstances, they would still have to be designated for Temple use. As such, one who derives benefit from them would be guilty of trespass against the Temple. Just as the Talmud ([Avodah Zarah 13a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=27&daf=13&format=pdf)) states that we no longer designate things to the Temple because of the problems it causes, so too the *mitzvah* of blowing the trumpets was discontinued so as not to cause problems:

> אכן זה לא מסתבר לומר דא"א לקיים המצוה של והרעתם בחצוצרות אלא בחצוצרות שהשתמשו בפועל במקדש כי למה לא סגי אם הי' עושים חצוצרות שיהי' מיועדים להשתמש בהם במקדש וא"כ למה כ' החינוך שמצוה זו אינה נוהגת אלא בזמן הבית
>
> והנה על תמיהת האחרונים למה מנה הרמב"ם בסה"מ מ' נ"ט תקיעת חצוצרות בשעת הקרבת קרבנות המועדים ותקיעת חצוצרות בעת צרה למצוה אחת תי' דס"ל להרמב"ם דתקיעות בשעת הקרבת הקרבנות צורך הקרבן הוא והו"ל חלק ממצות הקרבן הילכך אין למנותה במנין בפ"ע ומעתה אם החצוצרות הם חלק ממצות הקרבן לכאו"נ דהתוקע בו להנאתו במעילה קאי ואף שעומדת גם לתקיעות בעת צרה מידי דהוי אשמן המשחה דעומדת גם למשוח מלכים הנהנה ממנו במעילה קאי (ע' כריתות דף ה' שמא ח"ו מעלתי בשמן המשחה וע' מנ"ח מ' ק"ח דיש בשמן המשחה גם לאו דמעילה כמו בכל הקדשי)ם
>
> והואיל וקיי"ל דאין מקדישין בזה"ז משום דחיישינן לתקלה ע' ע"ז י"ג ובכ"מ שמא י"ל דזה הטעם שמצוה זו של חצוצרות שתוקעין בעת צרה אינה נוהגת בזה"ז כמ"ש החינוך משום לתא דתקלה

Comment: How does it follow from the Gemara in A"Z?  For normal things there's no point in being makdish them, so you're just asking for trouble for no reason.  For trumpets there's a very good reason to be makdish them, so that you can use them to fulfill the mitzvah.

Comment: @Heshy True. He doesn't address that. And it's perhaps even worse because it causes the total uprootion of a mitzvah, something which he himself says earlier in the responsum the Rabbis can't do